# Bootstrap navbar dropdown hidden behind grid content

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have looked up this problem and the solutions mentioned in other posts did not work for me.

What is happening: My dropdown on the navbar is being hidden behind an image, but only when the image is in Bootstrap grids. If I remove the grid and just use a div row element, the dropdown appears over the image. All the fixes I found were using z-index, which I tried but for some reason putting the z-index of the navbar, dropdown, li elements did not fix this problem.

This is a link to the HTML with the problem: http://ratchetmedia.com/bootstrap/
Hover over "Something2" on the navbar to see the dropdown. Tested and problem exists in IE and Chrome for me.

I really need to use the grid under the navbar in a few cases, otherwise I would have just done the job another way.

Thank you for your time and any input is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Just add z-index: 1 and position: relative on .headercontainer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set a position on `.headercontainer` for `z-index` to work. Just add these rules to the class.

```
position: relative;
z-index: 1;
```

Comment: Thanks, that fixed it! I really appreciate the quick reply!